# Message headers not included in error handling with Spring Integration DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to track all transactions adding extra headers on each operation, these extra headers work fine with request and response, but in error case no headers are included.

This is my configuration (with Spring Integration DSL and Java 1.7)

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(simpleMessageListenerContainer())
        .mappedReplyHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
        .mappedRequestHeaders(AMQPConstants.AMQP_CUSTOM_HEADER_FIELD_NAME_MATCH_PATTERN)
        .errorChannel(gatewayErrorChannel())
        .requestChannel(gatewayRequestChannel())
        .replyChannel(gatewayResponseChannel())
    )
    .transform(getCustomFromJsonTransformer())
    .route(new HeaderValueRouter(AMQPConstants.OPERATION_ROUTING_KEY))
    .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayRequestChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayResponseChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayErrorChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean       
public IntegrationFlow responseTrackerOutboundFlow() {      
    return trackerOutboundFlowTemplate(gatewayResponseChannel());       
}

@Bean       
public IntegrationFlow errorTrackerOutboundFlow() {     
    return trackerOutboundFlowTemplate(gatewayErrorChannel());      
}

private IntegrationFlow trackerOutboundFlowTemplate(MessageChannel fromMessageChannel) {        
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fromMessageChannel)        
        .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(new RabbitTemplate(getConnectionFactory()))
                .exchangeName(LOGGER_EXCHANGE_NAME)
                .routingKey(LOGGER_EXCHANGE_ROUTING_KEY)
                .mappedRequestHeaders("*"))     
         .get();        
}
```

I am using `errorChannel` for `inboundGateway` and also using `mappedReplyHeaders` and `mappedRequestHeaders`, is it possible to have headers in `errorChannel`? There is a way to configure mapped error headers or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mappedReplyHeaders` work only if you receive the good reply from the downstream flow. They are applied exactly before sending the reply message to the AMQP.

The `errorChannel` is a part of integration messaging, therefore no access to the `mappedReplyHeaders` at all. Forget them here!

From other side the `errorChannel` is responsible to wrap an `Exception` into the new `ErrorMessage`. That's why you don't see your headers there directly.

But you should bare in mind that integration messaging in most cases is `MessagingException` with the `failedMessage` property. That `failedMessage` is a "guilty" message for an exception.

And if the normal headers population process is done everywhere, you can get access to your headers from this `failedMessage` of the `MessagingException` `payload` of the `ErrorMessage` in the `errorChannel` flow.